# Getting error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python

```py
import os
find_ext = ('.txt',)

file_paths = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:\\'):
    for file in files:
        file_paths, file_ext = os.path.splitext(root+'\\'+file)
        if file_ext in find_ext:
            file_paths.append(root+'\\'+file)
```

I keep getting `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'` and am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: You appear to be redefining `file_paths`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You overwrite the `file_path` array with a string.  The latter doesn't have an `append` method as indicated by the error message.  As you don't have a use for the string just extract the `file_ext`:

```
import os
find_ext = ('.txt',)

file_paths = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:\\'):
    for file in files:
        file_ext = os.path.splitext(root+'\\'+file)[1]
        if file_ext in find_ext:
            file_paths.append(root+'\\'+file)
```